# How can I get as a result, the value of a child in XML file using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file with three levels. What I wanted to do is get the value of child as a result.

In this cases (lastname value"Watson") So I want to receive "Watson" as a result.

XML File:

```
<employees>
  <employee Id="default">
         <firstname>John</firstname>
         <lastname value="Watson"/>
 </employee>
</employees>
```

My XPath expresion is:

```
expr = xpath.compile("//employees/employee[@Id='default']/firstname/text()");
```

This expresion is working fine in my code and I can see "John" as a result.

The problem is when I try to get "Watson" as a result.

Could somebody tell me how I should build the expression?

Many thanks.

Cheers
Javi

Comment: Please use `/employees` instead of `//employees` to select the root element. It's much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expr = xpath.compile("//employees/employee[@Id='default']/lastname/@value");
```